# Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the curve $y = 9 - x^2$ and the line $y = 5$ about $y = 2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the curve $y = 9 - x^2$ and the line $y = 5$ about $y = 2$ using both the disk/washer and cylindrical shell method.

I know how to use the above method if it is a revolution around the axes but how do we use it to find the volume around a line?

Answer (score 1):

For disc method: The distance between $y=5$ and $y=2$ ise $5-2=3$ and the distance between $y=9-x^2$ and $y=2$ is $(9-x^2)-2=7-x^2$.

The intersection points are ($9-x^2=5$ gives) $x=\pm 2$.

Therefore the volume is $$\int_{-2}^2\pi((7-x^2)^2-3^2)dx.$$

For shell method: Write the function as two fuctions $x=\pm \sqrt{9-y}$. Then height is $\sqrt{9-y}-(-\sqrt{9-y})$ and the radius is $y-2$. The $y$ values change between $5$ and $9$.

Therefore, the volume is $$\int_5^9 2\pi (y-2)(2\sqrt{9-y})dy.$$